# Are Padma-Vyuha and Chakra-Vyuha the same?

Tags: mahabharata, vyuha

The Padma Vyuha is often confused with the Chakravyuha, as many writers use these terms interchangeably. It is told in Mahabharata that Chakravyuha was used in the 13-th day and padma-Vyuha on 15-th day. Are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both battle formations appear to be different. The [Critical Edition of the Mahābhārata](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html) uses "Cakravyūha" (wheel formation) to describe the formation Droṇa constructed on the 13<sup>th</sup> day of the war in which Abhimanyu was killed.

> 07,033.012   saṃjaya uvāca
>
> 07,033.012a   **cakravyūho** mahārāja ācāryeṇābhikalpitaḥ
>   07,033.012c   tatra śakropamāḥ sarve rājāno viniveśitāḥ
>
> Sanjaya replied, “O great king! **The preceptor created the chakra vyuha**. All the kings, who were Shakra’s equal, were assembled in it....
>
> (English translation from [The Mahabharata: Volume 6 by Bibek Debroy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYNFH75))

[The Southern Recension of the Mahābhārata](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-sarit.html) however calls the same, Padmavyūha (lotus formation). And this is probably why the terms are often used interchangeably.

> 7.34. adhyAyaH 034
>
> Mahabharata - Drona Parva - Chapter Topics
>
> **droNena padmavyUharachanA**.. 1 ..
>
> 7-34-0
>
> sa~njaya uvAcha. 7-34-0x
>
> sthiro bhava mahArAja shokaM dhAraya durdharam. 
>   mahAntaM bandhunAshaM te kathayiShyAmi tachChR^ishu.. 7-34-1
>
> **padmavyUho** mahArAja AchAryeNAbhikalpitaH. 
>   tatra padmopamAH sarve rAjAno viniveshitAH.. 7-34-2

On the 14<sup>th</sup> day, to protect Jayadratha, Droṇa constructs an even more intricate formation, part *padma* (lotus) and part *śakaṭa* (cart) but makes no reference to the Cakravyūha he constructed the previous day so it's possible this is an entirely different formation.

> Chapter 1030 (53)
>
> 07,053.027a   **śakaṭaḥ padmapaś cārdho vyūho** droṇena kalpitaḥ
>   07,053.027c   padmakarṇikamadhyasthaḥ sūcīpāśe jayadrathaḥ
>   07,053.027e   sthāsyate rakṣito vīraiḥ sindhurāḍ yuddhadurmadaiḥ
>
> Drona will construct a vyuha at the rear. **Half of this will be in the form of a cart** and **half in the form of a lotus**. There will be an array in the form of a needle in the midst of the pericarp of the lotus. Jayadratha, the king of Sindhu who is unassailable in battle, will be stationed there, protected by brave ones.
>
> Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 6 (pp. 61-62)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.